# Prevent fragment re-create in viewpager

Tags: android, fragment, state

I want to prevent fragment re-create in viewpager , in default way every time you navigate to a fragment in viewpager , android creates a new instance of that fragment.
setOffscreenPageLimit(x) can fix this problem but i don't want to load more fragments in activity's onCreate. Any idea to solve this problem and maintain fragment instance after select for next time?

Answer (score 2):

There are two most used classes for View Pagers are:

- [FragmentPagerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html)
- [FragmentStatePagerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html)

and they look alike in many ways but not all.

What you need is **FragmentPagerAdapter**

This will keep the Fragment as you want and not being recreated each time as the following quote say from the official documentantion:

> Implementation of PagerAdapter that represents each page as a Fragment that is persistently kept in the fragment manager as long as the user can return to the page.

And also here in the same documentation:

> The fragment of each page the user visits will be kept in memory...

Although remember using this, memory will be your responsibility and you will have to manage memory of your Views check the number of pages you are having first if they are many, its not a nice idea to display 50 pages this way. Only may be less than 10 (*Tabs may be its the best choice*). You are good. Memory management is the only thing to take **NOTE** here as the documentation itself say:

> This can result in using a significant amount of memory since fragment instances can hold on to an arbitrary amount of state. For larger sets of pages, consider `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`.

So change your adapter to `FragmentPagerAdapter` and your fragments will be kept in memory not recreated.

Comment: After downvoting please leave a comment! It is usually not a good idea to keep the answer as it is, if you find it useless! Say something so that we can edit or remove it!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting [Fragment.setRetainInstance(true)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance(boolean)). If you use FragmentPagerAdapter, this will cause an existing fragment to 'live' and not get re-created. It will to get detached and re-attached instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, where you set the view pager adapter

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(numberOfFragments)
```